# Wrap lines to a specified number of fields

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file which contains several vectors, as follows. The components of these vectors are separated with space and they are spanned in a few lines. This file is generated after I run a command in the Ubuntu terminal.

```
0 -1 -0.494 0.12 -0.919 0.112 0.914 -0.681 -0.067 -0.918 -0.443 -0.216 -0.48 0.55 0.701 0.429 0.699 -0.726 -0.39 0.172 0.61 -0.599 0.728 -0.883 -0.32 0.044 -0.189 -0.732 -0.309 -0.286 -0.859 0.107 0.298 
0 0 0.869 0.641 -0.331 -0.631 -0.236 0.303 0.998 0.153 -0.89 -0.927 -0.671 -0.478 0.693 -0.007 -0.64 0.091 -0.249 -0.881 0.641 0.689 0.222 -0.398 0.548 -0.268 -0.877 -0.333 -0.55 0.858 0.504 0.215 -0.178 
0 0 0 0.758 -0.214 0.768 0.329 0.667 -0.013 0.367 0.103 -0.307 -0.565 0.685 0.171 -0.903 0.32 -0.682 -0.887 -0.44 -0.467 0.409 -0.649 0.249 0.772 -0.962 0.443 -0.594 0.776 -0.427 0.088 -0.971 0.938
```

How can I convert this file into another file using shell commands with the following format, where each vector is in a separate line and the header of the file is the number of three-component vectors?

```
n
V1x V1y V1z
V2x V2y V2z
V3x V3y V3z
...
Vnx Vny Vnz
```

where n is the number of three-component vectors in the file. In the file that I have: `V1x=0`, `V1y=-1`, `V1z=-0.494`. `V2x=0.12`, `V2y=-0.919`, `V2z=0.112` and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Perl one-liner:

```
perl -p00E 'y/\n/ /;say s/(\S+\s+){3}\K/\n/g' file
```

Note that both this solution and [Gnouc's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130818/26909) assume the file is small enough to be stored in memory as a whole.

**Explanation**

- `-p` means alias each record of the file to `$_` and print the contents of `$_` after each record has been processed.
- `-00` means set the record separator to null in order to read the whole file in as one record.
- `-E` means treat the following string as Perl code. Using `-E` instead of the usual `-e` means I can use the `say` feature.
- `y/\n/ /` makes the whole file one line (note that `y///` is a synonym of `tr///` in Perl in order to oblige `sed` users).
- `s/(\S+\s+){3}\K/\n/g` means append a new line after every pattern of (non-whitespace followed by whitespace repeated 3 times == a vector).
- Since `s///` will return the number of substitutions it has successfully made, using it as an argument to `say` will print out the number of substitutions (=vectors).
- After the count is printed, the contents of `$_` are then printed because we used `-p`.

**Update**

If you want the maximum value:

```
perl -p00E 'y/\n/ /;s/(\S+\s+){1}\K/\n/g' file | sort -nr | head -1
```

**The advantage of this solution**

It only has one "magic number". In other words, if you suddenly started working with 2D vectors, all you need to do is change the `{3}` in the code to `{2}`.

**The disadvantage of this solution**

If you're unfamiliar with Perl, it reads like a black magic spell.

Comment: Thank you. It is a great solution. I started learning Perl to fully understand the answers for this post.

Comment: @Ahm I'm glad I could help. Please don't forget to mark the answer 'Accepted' if it helped you. As an additional piece of advice: if your work involves manipulating many textual files (like in this example), you would benefit a lot from learning a scripting language like Perl, Python, Ruby or Tcl.

Comment: How can I also skip printing the number of vectors?

Comment: @A2009 just remove `say`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. I modified your super flexible code in order to find the maximum of the values. So I changed it to `perl -p00E 'y/\n/ /; s/(\S+\s+){1}\K/\n/g' file` to wrap the each number in a separate line. Now I want to find the maximum value. Could you help me with this too?

Comment: @A2009 Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
ruby -e 'ns = STDIN.read.split(/\s+/); puts(ns.size/3); 0.step(ns.size,3) do |i| puts(ns[i,3].join(" ")) end' < yourfile
```

should work, if you allow external programs to be called from the shell.

Edit: Maybe we should take this on the golf course :-)

Comment: "Maybe we should take this on the golf course" Challenge gladly accepted. Please see my updated answer :)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do two things:

- re-wrap the data to have exactly 3 coordinates per line;
- prefix a line with the number of vectors.

It is simpler to handle this as two successive, independent problems. First, rewrap the data. You can use awk for this, telling it that any sequence of whitespace is an input record separator.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{if (NR % 3) printf "%s ", $0; else print}' <input.txt >wrapped.txt
```

You can make this a little shorter by setting the output separator to a newline on lines numbers that are a multiple of 3, and a space otherwise.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{ORS = NR % 3 ? " " : "\n"; print}' <input.txt >wrapped.txt
```

Since printing is the default action, this can be shortened to

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'ORS = NR % 3 ? " " : "\n"' <input.txt >wrapped.txt
```

The number of vectors is the number of lines in the intermediate files.

```
wc -l wrapped.txt >output.txt
cat wrapped.txt >>output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -anle 'push @e,@F; 
END {
    print @e/3;
    for ($i=0;$i<@e;$i+=3) {
        printf "%-6s %-6s %-6s\n",$e[$i],$e[$i+1],$e[$i+2];
    }
} ' file
33
0      -1     -0.494
0.12   -0.919 0.112 
0.914  -0.681 -0.067
-0.918 -0.443 -0.216
-0.48  0.55   0.701 
0.429  0.699  -0.726
-0.39  0.172  0.61  
-0.599 0.728  -0.883
-0.32  0.044  -0.189
-0.732 -0.309 -0.286
-0.859 0.107  0.298 
0      0      0.869 
0.641  -0.331 -0.631
-0.236 0.303  0.998 
0.153  -0.89  -0.927
-0.671 -0.478 0.693 
-0.007 -0.64  0.091 
-0.249 -0.881 0.641 
0.689  0.222  -0.398
0.548  -0.268 -0.877
-0.333 -0.55  0.858 
0.504  0.215  -0.178
0      0      0     
0.758  -0.214 0.768 
0.329  0.667  -0.013
0.367  0.103  -0.307
-0.565 0.685  0.171 
-0.903 0.32   -0.682
-0.887 -0.44  -0.467
0.409  -0.649 0.249 
0.772  -0.962 0.443 
-0.594 0.776  -0.427
0.088  -0.971 0.938
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting feature of the bash shell's `printf` builtin

```
  The format is reused as necessary to consume all  of  the  argu‐
  ments.
```

which appears to allow us to slurp up a file of whitespace-separated values and spit them out three-to-a-line using a simple printf

```
printf '%8.3f %8.3f %8.3f\n' $(<file)
```

(I've used `8.3` floating-point format just to prettify the output, but you could use `%s` to echo each field as a raw string).

To count the resulting vectors you could just use `wc` - if you don't mind the count coming *after* the data then you could just tee the output

```
printf '%8.3f %8.3f %8.3f\n' $(<file) | tee >(wc -l)
```

If you really insist on putting the count at the top, then one possibility might be to print to a variable, then count and print the variable (this will be subject to the same memory considerations as other in-place methods)

```
printf -v vecs '%8.3f %8.3f %8.3f\n' $(<file)
wc -l < <(printf "$vecs") ; printf "$vecs"
```

If you're a real shell purist then you could use `mapfile` (or its synonym `readarray`) to shove the re-formatted data into an array instead of a string variable - and then use the shell's `${#array[@]}` count operator to avoid an external call to `wc`

```
mapfile vecs < <(printf '%8.3f %8.3f %8.3f\n' $(<file))
printf '%d\n' ${#vecs[@]} ; printf '%s' "${vecs[@]}"
```

The final printf makes use of the format reuse feature again to print each newline-terminated array element in turn.